# Our notification bar not works on mobile devices as expected

Tags: html, css, scroll, media, marquee

We have our website in wordpress, below is the link for your reference.

```
https://timesandtrendsacademy.com/
```

There is one foobar which is shown at the bottom of every page of our website in sticky and scrolling mode.
I have put some custom css for the same for full width look, below for your reference,

```
.foobar-container-left{display:none;}
.foobar-container-right{display:none;}
#foobar-message-0{width:100%;}

@media only screen and (max-width:500){
#branches{width:100%;}
}
```

It's working perfect on desktop, but when we resizing our screen or when we open on mobile devices that width is not taking a full-width.
It is showing in a 150px width size that is not looking good in mobile devices.

we have to add some css or media query to reflect proper on all the devices.

Please advice us.

Thanks,
Gopal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because there's a style with a `!important` that overwrites your styles.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) and (min-width: 320px) {
    #foobar-message-0 {
        margin-top: 10px;
        width: 150px!important;
    }
}
```

Remove the !important, edit the style, or use a more specific selector with !important.

Example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    #foobar-message-0 {
        width: 100%!important;
    }
}
```

These styles should be after the styles to overwrite.

Comment: Tryed but not working with mobile devices, still showing as it is in mobile devices

Comment: You add the styles in head before the stylesheet (style.css). The stylesheet is overriding your style. Put de style tag after the stylesheet or put the styles within the stylesheet at the end.

Comment: Working perfect, now it will go little bit below, so how do i align center vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Add this css in style editor

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
.foobar-container-inner {
    margin-left: 0important;
    width:100%!important;
    margin-top: -40px!important;
}
#foobar-message-0 {
    width:100%!important;
}
}
```

Comment: Working perfect now, but how do i align in center vertically.

Comment: Hello @GopalKshirsagar sorry for late answer, but you can check updated answer for center vertically and add it, changes - have added     margin-top: -40px!important; in 'foobar-container-inner' class